# How to post an image to the web services

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

In my project:-

1)click a picture from camera(don't save it).

2)show a cropped image with 2 buttons post and cancel.where post button post the image and cancel button discard the image.it looks something like this.
[image: 2nd]

I don't know how to post the camera capture image.I searched over the internet find a lot of codes but didn't find any code that helps me out.

I tried code given on these links..

[First](http://www.iriphon.com/2011/11/09/ios-uploading-an-image-from-your-iphone-to-a-server/) ,[Second](http://code.developwithus.com/iphone/upload-image-and-data-with-iphone-sdk/) ,[Third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319823/newbie-having-issues-with-uploading-a-file-using-asihttprequest), and many others.

I wish someone will help..how to post??   thanks.

```
-(IBAction)sendRequest:(id)sender {

     #define DataDownloaderRunMode @"myapp.run_mode" 

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url 
                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                       timeoutInterval:60]; 

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 

        NSString *boundary = @"----WebKitFormBoundarycC4YiaUFwM44F6rT";

        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment[file]";
        filename="picture.png"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                               delegate:self 
                                                               startImmediately:NO]; 

        [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:DataDownloaderRunMode]; 

        [connection start];
}
```

and connecting this to post button..

Comment: that first link does exactly what you want, if you are having specific problems you should post your code and any errors

Comment: @wattson12            when i use code of first link it shows error in this line...[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment[file]";
filename="picture.png"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: @wattson12     the error is expected ' '.but i don't know where....

Comment: @user1865424 you use the link which i give you dude?? follow that tutorials??

Comment: show your code? what's the response you are getting from server?

Comment: @NSIllusion      my code shows error..so,no response getting...but i am showing my code..i am editing above...

Comment: @user1865424: Have you setup the delegate methods for `NSURLConnection` ?
Use them to fetch response from the webserver to which you are uploading the image.
And can you edit your question with those error messages ?

Comment: @Rajneesh071      no not yet...now i posting is happening  but image not get posted....can u help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"picture.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Here your database field name for store the image is `picture` then write the field name in `name` parameter...

use this code...

Comment: which error you get and what you write code dude???

Comment: what is in the link i just copied and paste...error is executed ','

Comment: You have to escape the quotes.  `filename=\"picture.png\"`

Comment: yes also right dude and another is i edit now...

Comment: Also, don't remove the \r\n from the line. It should be there.

Comment: @user1865424 now just use above code dude now i update it and also here attachment[file] what is this??

Comment: @Tim thank you u r right dude now just see the code thanx mate?? :)

Comment: no no dude , if this is a onetype of variable then i write this name dude just see i write the variable at last and put the %@ which pass the value of this variable otherwise use direct with that name i dont know about that , so use this also see [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment[file]\"; filename=\"picture.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: now use this code dude....

Comment: @user1865424 attachment[file] is a variable of simple string ??

Comment: is the **Dude** word is prefix for every comment ?

Comment: what is the field name where you store this image?? write the field name instead of  attachment[file]

Comment: @RDC no but i dont know why all friends write this and speak.. i think this is good for communication... what you say??

Comment: @user1865424 first tell me , what is the field name in which you store this image in database??

Comment: @ParasJoshi appreciate your Helping effort dear! but on SO please keep in mind [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) too, hope you got me!

Comment: @user1865424 see i have a database in which i upload the vedio and i pass the data with this line just try to understand what i want to say.. [postBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 here my field name is "video" for store the vedio so just tell me what is the field name of image you stored??

Comment: @RDC ok ok thanx i try to understand it...

Comment: @ParasJoshi      come on chat...

Comment: but give me link please for chat here

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21045/discussion-between-user1865424-and-paras-joshi open it

Comment: @ParasJoshi      send me the chat link...so,we can chat...pls..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21799/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-user1865424)

Comment: good good @user1865424 now complete whole task??

Comment: just click on above letuse continuew link

Comment: @user1865424 http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21799/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-user1865424 open this

Comment: @ParasJoshi       Happy new year dude..

Comment: happy new year you too come for lunch dude..

Comment: yes dude whats up?? and now i have work dude for create one demo with multiple view universal dude :(

Comment: ok dude i post the comment on this ok dude...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22051/discussion-between-user1865424-and-paras-joshi)

Comment: ok come on chat of above link..

Comment: yes what dude?? common on chat..

Comment: sorry dude for late reply but now i have not time .. from some time i also not use stackoverflow bcoz i have not time so.. sorry bro... i will post comment when i will free..

Comment: @ParasJoshi     dude need some help..if u have time come online..plz...

Comment: @ParasJoshi Hey dude after such a long time..How r u??

Answer (score 2):

```
// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

Follow this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042360/nsdata-and-uploading-images-via-post-in-ios)

Or you can use ASIHTTP classes for this

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL/Service.asmx/RegisterClient?"]];
            request.delegate=self;

            encodedImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgRef);

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgRef) forKey:@"userImage"];

            str =[Base64 encode:encodedImage];

           [request setPostValue:email.text forKey:@"Email"];

            [request setPostValue:name.text forKey:@"FName"];
            [request setPostValue:str forKey:@"UserImage"];
            [request setPostValue:dob.text forKey:@"dob"];
            [request setPostValue:phoneNumber.text forKey:@"Phone"];
            [request setPostValue:ggg.text forKey:@"Gender"];
            [request setPostValue:address.text forKey:@"Address"];
            [request setPostValue:interest.text forKey:@"Interest"];

            [request startAsynchronous];
```

[ASIHTTPRequest documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Comment: tnx dude..but i tried that link also...nt getting..

Comment: what is the problem with you?